# Restkit + Magical Record issue finding sql file

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, magicalrecord

I am trying to use restkit with magical record.

So I've set it up as per the following URL:
https://github.com/blakewatters/RKMagicalRecord

My issue is that if I try to create a record using Magic Record, I always get the following error the first time it tries to save anything. If I close the app and restart it , it is ok.

+MagicalRecord(ErrorHandling) defaultErrorHandler: Error: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1CECA7F7-510F-47F2-9F2D-4D0346C4E74F/Documents/WhateverModel.sqlite

This means it can't find the file. So I checked the folder and yes it is not there even though I instructed restkit to set it up.

Any idea why am getting this?

Setup code below

```
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Model" ofType:@"momd"]];
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Model.sqlite"];
NSError *error = nil;
[managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure MagicalRecord to use RestKit's Core Data stack
[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_setDefaultStoreCoordinator:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreCoordinator];
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setRootSavingContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setDefaultContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ROOT_URL]];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
```

Creating and saving Object below:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    WhateverObject *obj = [WhateverObject createInContext:localContext];
}completion:^(BOOL successful, NSError *error) {

    if(successful){

    }else{

    }
}];
```

Comment: how did you instruct RestKit to set it up?

Comment: I followed the project in https://github.com/blakewatters/RKMagicalRecord

Comment: Show your code in the question, both for setup and the save, and show full error message and stack trace.

Comment: Hi basically, i think the issues comes with the fact that I am using Magic record to create the objects and save. I use the saveblock for this.[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext)

Comment: You might need to call [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator]; right after you created the managedObjectStore

Comment: Still no luck. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I removed Magical Record and used the following to set it up:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ROOT_URL]];

NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
/**
 Complete Core Data stack initialization
 */
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"WhateverModel.sqlite"];

NSError *error;

NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil  withConfiguration:nil options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error];

NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```